# Garbage Collection Event

Tags: java, jpa, garbage-collection

Can we get the event in a class like when I am going to be garbage collected?

Let me explain the thing:

I am using **JPA API** to get database objects.
So the scene is that we have to open the **EntityManager**, **call the 
respective things** and **close it before leaving.**

But if unintentionally if someone forgot to close the entitymanager next all queries to same data base gives previous un-updated results. :(

My point is is by any means I get the event of something like you are going to be destroyed in that case I will write the code that **this.entitymanager.close()**, in that way every time the **entitymanager** object **closes itself if user forget to close the next time Garbage Collector comes to collect it**.

i know destructor thing is not possible, but whats the best way of handling this?

Comment: if you do not inject you persistence context, try - finally is your friend...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this would help you;

```
@Override
protected void finalize() {
    try {
        close();        // close EntityManager connection
    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

Finalize is called when the Object is scheduled for Garbage Collection.

Comment: There is no guarantee to finalize being called so I suppose that's not an option

Comment: @PetrMensik Is that just if the application is terminated abruptly? Such as through `System.exit()`

Comment: +1 this is the best option available apart from fixing the code so the resource is always cleaned up correctly. You could log the stack trace where the resource was created if it wasn't closed so you can track down the source of the bug.

Comment: @Jivings if the JVM never runs out of memory the GC might never be called.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I also thought that callign finalize is not generally recommended as a best practise (actually I've never seen that in any code)

Comment: @PetrMensik Its not best practice, but its better than nothing. e.g. it is recommended that you close() resources like Sockets or File Streams when you have finished with them. Never the less they have finalize() methods which will close them later.  IMHO It should also report an error with information to help you fix your bug.